# How to remove the legend key border in ggplot's geom_sf?

Tags: r, ggplot2

By default `geom_sf` draws a legend whose keys (in the fill color) are surrounded by a frame in the border color (i.e., the `color` aesethetic). Is there a way to remove this frame? Apparently, this frame is *inside* the key rectangle so it cannot be overwritten by modifying `legend.key` in the example below.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(spData)

spData::world %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = continent)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = "red"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Ideally, I would not only remove the frames but also remvoe the vertical space between the legend keys entirely, similar to the appearance of `guide_colorsteps`.

My hacky attempt here succeeds in removing the frames but the rectangles are not perfectly adjacent yet. Is there a) a less hacky way to remove the frames, and b) a way to remove the vertical space between the rectangles altogether?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(spData)

spData::world %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = continent, color = continent)) +
  geom_sf(data = st_geometry(spData::world), fill = NA, color = "black") + 
  theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(0, 'cm')) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(byrow = TRUE))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible option which does not require to use `theme` or `guides` would be to set the `key_glyph` to `"rect"`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.4.3, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(spData)
#> To access larger datasets in this package, install the spDataLarge
#> package with: `install.packages('spDataLarge',
#> repos='https://nowosad.github.io/drat/', type='source')`

spData::world %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = continent)) +
  geom_sf(key_glyph = "rect", color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't think there could be anything more elegant than this. Seems like I should finally go and read the ggplot book front to back to learn what else is hiding behind the dots. Grüße nach Freiburg!